# git error while trying to checkout branch

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am getting this error while trying to do git checkout:

```
git checkout BranchName
```

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:

```
git status
On branch BranchName
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/BranchName' by 5 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
```

I do not want to commit these changes.

How to ignore these file types while doing checkout:

- target
- out
- *.log
- *.iml
- .idea
- .slcache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you do not want git stop you to switch to a different branch** (since working tree has un-committed the changes), just force switch to another branch by adding `-f` option in `git checkout branchname` command:

```
git checkout branchname -f
```

**If you do not want to track cretain folders and file types in git repo any more**, you can add the folders and files with wildcards in `.gitignore` and remove the caches in git repo:

```
# Add .gitignore file
touch .gitignore
```

Then add below lines in `.gitignore` contents:

```
target
out
*.log
*.iml
.idea
.slcache
```

And execute the commands:

```
git rm target --cached
git rm out --cached
git rm *.log --cached -r
git rm *.iml --cached -r
git rm .idea --cached
git rm .slcache --cached
git add .
git commit -m 'ignore certain files from git repo'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to keep your changes at all, you can simply undo the changes.

```
# Warning: you will lose any uncommitted changes
git checkout -- <files>
```

If you want to keep the changes for later, but don't want to commit them, you could stash them, which saves them in a stash and returns your working tree to before you made those changes

```
git stash
```

To see/restore your stash(es)

```
# Shows list of your stashes
git stash list

# Shows the specific changes in the most recent stash
git stash show

# Applies the most recent stash to your working tree
git stash apply

# Applies the most recent stash to your working tree and removes the stash from your stashes
git stash pop
```

Comment: but those files are not stashing

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you want to `checkout` to the other branch you need to do some job with your changes. Those are

- If you need your change further you can `stash` it. [For more](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)
- If you don't need your change than you can use `reset`. [For more](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)
- you can also can take the advantages of `cherrypick` if you need the changes further. [For more](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)

> For checkout: target out *.log *.iml .idea .slcache

you can create `.gitignore` file and than you can configure this file with what you wanted.

EX: for ignoring `*.log` file 
In `.gitignore` file put as `*.log` and for `directory` put as `**/directory_name`. [For more help](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/gitignore#git-ignore-patterns)